# mailto link is not working in pdf using adobe's pdf embed api

Tags: pdf, adobe

I am using adobe's pdf embed API to display pdf in the asp.net web application. In pdf mailto link is not working while other links work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the job:
Start > Default Programs > Set program access and computer defaults > custom drop down. Then enable access to Thunderbird under the default email program option.
(This worked for me)

[See this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/mailto-link-not-working/m-p/6128262)

[See this (2)](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/html-links-email-links-working-q133850.aspx)

Comment: default e-mail program is not a problem. default e-mail problem is already set. i am displaying pdf in web page using the code from the link.https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html